# Need faster method to import large CSV file to Azure SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, csv, import

Need suggestions in below scenario:

We have to import data from large CSV files (>=1GB) to target Azure SQL DB.

Currently using SQL server 2012's "Import and Export data" utility to do it.

Problem: 
1. The rate of importing is very slow. Its importing 1.6 million records (256 MB CSV) in 5 1/2 hrs which is expensive wrt time and cost.

Are there any suggestions to load csv data faster?

Note: 
1. CSV files contains (,) in data with (") as text field separator

2. Source has all types of data - date, int, decimal

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you able to install the SQL Utilities (BCP and SQLCMD) and use those? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp

Comment: Hi @JacobH I have the utilities installed but the problem is bcp doesnt support comma in the data. My data can contain comma e.g: "first, second" should be imported as one column. have i misunderstood something?

Comment: Oh you are right. Unless you can change the delimiter to something else. Are you able to use something like Python? It would be a relatively small script to use a [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect) and insert rows to [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python?tabs=windows). I don't know that it is guaranteed to improve on the Import and Export Data utility though. The ability to bulk insert makes a difference in magnitudes, but Python may increase the speed to an acceptable level.

Comment: @User2019 I'm agree with Jacob H. I updated my answer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you is using [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). It has good performance to transfer big data.

[image]

You can store you csv file to many date store(supported by Data Factory):

[image]
[image]

Then copy the csv file to Azure SQL database.

You may need reference these tutorials:

1. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

Update:

Your csv file has the column data which contains comma ",".

Many people have post same questions, I also have asked Azure Support for helps, the have the same suggestion like @Jacob H told you in comment: alter the csv file or try other ways.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Leon, Thanks you so much for checking and replying however we wanted to avoid data factory due to cost, changing delimiter can be checked but csv is a basic and widely used format and data can contain comma is also a very common scenario, wondering if there are any other workaround?

Comment: @User2019 According my experience, there's no good solutions. No matter if you user DF or not, the csv  column data contains comma ",", it will cause the schema mapping error, may get more  data or miss some columns.  You can google or search this kind of problems in Stack overflow. Waiting for some days, if still no one can give you any workarounds, then hope you can mark it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @User2019, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.